# Fade images when loaded and changed in Blazor (server) app

Tags: css, animation, blazor, blazor-server-side

I've got a Blazor server app which displays a grid of images. I want to have the images fade when they're displayed. I'm currently using a CSS style/animation:

```
.gridimage {
    animation: fadeIn ease 1s;
}

<img class="gridimage" src="@ImageUrl">
```

This works fine on initial page load - but when a user changes a filter criteria and the grid of images changes, my @code updates the `@ImageUrl` and I call `StateHasChanged`, but the fade doesn't kick in, because the image has already loaded.

I've thought about trying a different approach, where I define a JS method:

```
function fadeIn(obj) {
            obj.style.transition = "opacity 1s";
            obj.style.opacity = "1";
        }
```

and then detect DOM changes and trigger that `fadeIn()` call when the img src attribute changes, but that feels kindof like fighting with the Blazor DOM update model. I've also toyed with using JSInterop when I update `ImageUrl` but again, it seems messy.

Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: Maybe try @key on your `<img @key="@ImageUrl" ... ` with the css approach.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10389#issuecomment-533581071

Comment: https://github.com/mikoskinen/Blazor.Animate

Comment: Unfortunately, Blazor.Animate doesn't solve the problem, because the animation still only gets called once when the image src changes several times.

Answer (score 2):

Turned out that Brian Parker's answer was correct; adding a unique `@key` to the item caused the CSS to re-trigger when the page transitions and the image updates - presumably because Blazor sees the `<img @key=1234>` item as different to `<img @key=1235>` and so forces it to re-evaluate the CSS.